# Trying to code 'rock paper scissors' game with tkinter. But my coding doesn't give what i want, and no error has occured

Tags: python, tkinter

So here's what I just did.

```
from tkinter import *
import random
window = Tk()

button_list=['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors']

RockImage=PhotoImage(file="rock.png")
PaperImage=PhotoImage(file="paper.png")
ScissorImage=PhotoImage(file="scissors.png")

  def update_image(num,Img):

     if num==1:
         inputLabel_1=Label(window, image=Img)
         inputLabel_1.grid(row=0, column=0)

    elif num==2:
        inputLabel_2=Label(window, image=Img)
        inputLabel_2.grid(row=0, column=2)


Mid_ResultLabel=Label(window, text=' ', fg='green')
ResultLabel=Label(window, text=' ',fg='green')
Mid_ResultLabel.grid(row=0, column=1)
ResultLabel.grid(row=1, column=1)


def game(choice):
    opponent = random.randint(1,3)
    if opponent == 1:
        update_image(2,RockImage)
    elif opponent == 2:
        update_image(2,PaperImage)
    elif opponent ==3:
        update_image(2,ScissorImage)

    if choice == 'Rock':
        update_image(1,RockImage)
        if opponent == 1:
            Mid_ResultLabel = Label(window, width=10, text='======')
            ResultLabel = Label(window, width=10, text='DRAW!',fg='green')
        elif opponent == 2:
            Mid_ResultLabel = Label(window, width=10, text='<<<<<<')
            ResultLabel = Label(window, width=10, text='LOSE...')
        elif opponent ==3:
            Mid_ResultLabel = Label(window, width=10, text='>>>>>>')
            ResultLabel = Label(window, width=10, text='YOU WON!')

    elif choice == 'Paper':
        update_image(1,PaperImage)
        if opponent == 1:
            Mid_ResultLabel = Label(window, width=10, text='>>>>>>')
            ResultLabel = Label(window, width=10, text='YOU WON!')
        elif opponent == 2:
            Mid_ResultLabel = Label(window, width=10, text='======')
            ResultLabel = Label(window, width=10, text='DRAW!')
        elif opponent == 3:
            Mid_ResultLabel = Label(window, width=10, text='<<<<<<')
            ResultLabel = Label(window, width=10, text='LOSE...')

    elif choice == 'Scissors':
        update_image(1,ScissorImage)
        if opponent == 1:
            Mid_ResultLabel = Label(window, width=10, text='<<<<<<')
            ResultLabel = Label(window, width=10, text='LOSE...')
        elif opponent == 2:
            Mid_ResultLabel = Label(window, width=10, text='>>>>>>')
            ResultLabel = Label(window, width=10, text='YOU WON!')
        elif opponent == 3 :
            Mid_ResultLabel = Label(window, width=10, text='======')
            ResultLabel = Label(window, width=10, text='DRAW!')

        Mid_ResultLabel.grid(row=0, column=1)
        ResultLabel.grid(row=1, column=1)


i=0
for button_text in button_list:
    def click(t=i):
            game(t)
    Button(window, text=button_text, width=30, command = click).grid(row=3, column = i)
    i+=1


window.mainloop()
```

I can't use canvas in this thing.. just allowed to use Labels.
Error does not appear when I run this. So I can't figure it out what is wrong.

What should I edit on here? Where did I made mistakes?

- [rock image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykN79.png)
- [paper image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHcK7.png)
- [scissors image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pBYN.png)

Comment: Whats wrong ? Your images dont show up ?

Comment: in 'def game():', the opponent's picture shows up, but mine doesn't...someone gave me the correction though!

Answer (score 0):

For a start, you pass to the `game` function an integer not a string, so when you check to see if it is rock, paper or scissors it never returns a value. This means you should change your code to read:

```py
if choice == 'Rock': -> if choice == 0:
elif choice == 'Paper': -> elif choice == 1:
elif choice == 'Scissors': -> elif choice == 2:
```

Furthermore, instead of rebuilding the labels you can use `label.configure` to change the text simply:

```py
if choice == 0:
    update_image(1,RockImage)
    if opponent == 1:
        Mid_ResultLabel.configure(text='======')
        ResultLabel.configure(text='DRAW!')
    elif opponent == 2:
        Mid_ResultLabel.configure(text='<<<<<<')
        ResultLabel.configure(text='LOSE...')
    elif opponent ==3:
        Mid_ResultLabel.configure(text=">>>>>>")
        ResultLabel.configure(text='YOU WON!')

elif choice == 1:
    update_image(1,PaperImage)
    if opponent == 1:
        Mid_ResultLabel.configure(text=">>>>>>")
        ResultLabel.configure(text='YOU WON!')
    elif opponent == 2:
        Mid_ResultLabel.configure(text='======')
        ResultLabel.configure(text='DRAW!')
    elif opponent == 3:
        Mid_ResultLabel.configure(text='<<<<<<')
        ResultLabel.configure(text='LOSE...')

elif choice == 2:
    update_image(1,ScissorImage)
    if opponent == 1:
        Mid_ResultLabel.configure(text='<<<<<<')
        ResultLabel.configure(text='LOSE...')
    elif opponent == 2:
        Mid_ResultLabel.configure(text=">>>>>>")
        ResultLabel.configure(text='YOU WON!')
    elif opponent == 3 :
        Mid_ResultLabel.configure(text='======')
        ResultLabel.configure(text='DRAW!')
```

There are more improvements you can also make to your code; however, these changes will make your code working!

#### Overall the code changes made

```py
from tkinter import *
import random
window = Tk()

button_list = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors']

RockImage = PhotoImage(file="rock.png")
PaperImage = PhotoImage(file="paper.png")
ScissorImage = PhotoImage(file="scissors.png")


def update_image(num, Img):
    if num == 1:
         inputLabel_1 = Label(window, image=Img)
         inputLabel_1.grid(row=0, column=0)
    elif num==2:
        inputLabel_2=Label(window, image=Img)
        inputLabel_2.grid(row=0, column=2)


Mid_ResultLabel=Label(window, text=' ', fg='green')
ResultLabel=Label(window, text=' ',fg='green')
Mid_ResultLabel.grid(row=0, column=1)
ResultLabel.grid(row=1, column=1)


def game(choice):
    print("GAME FUNCTION")
    opponent = random.randint(1,3)
    if opponent == 1:
        update_image(2,RockImage)
    elif opponent == 2:
        update_image(2,PaperImage)
    elif opponent ==3:
        update_image(2,ScissorImage)

    if choice == 0:
        update_image(1,RockImage)
        if opponent == 1:
            Mid_ResultLabel.configure(text='======')
            ResultLabel.configure(text='DRAW!')
        elif opponent == 2:
            Mid_ResultLabel.configure(text='<<<<<<')
            ResultLabel.configure(text='LOSE...')
        elif opponent ==3:
            Mid_ResultLabel.configure(text=">>>>>>")
            ResultLabel.configure(text='YOU WON!')

    elif choice == 1:
        update_image(1,PaperImage)
        if opponent == 1:
            Mid_ResultLabel.configure(text=">>>>>>")
            ResultLabel.configure(text='YOU WON!')
        elif opponent == 2:
            Mid_ResultLabel.configure(text='======')
            ResultLabel.configure(text='DRAW!')
        elif opponent == 3:
            Mid_ResultLabel.configure(text='<<<<<<')
            ResultLabel.configure(text='LOSE...')

    elif choice == 2:
        update_image(1,ScissorImage)
        if opponent == 1:
            Mid_ResultLabel.configure(text='<<<<<<')
            ResultLabel.configure(text='LOSE...')
        elif opponent == 2:
            Mid_ResultLabel.configure(text=">>>>>>")
            ResultLabel.configure(text='YOU WON!')
        elif opponent == 3 :
            Mid_ResultLabel.configure(text='======')
            ResultLabel.configure(text='DRAW!')


i=0
for button_text in button_list:
    def click(t=i):
            game(t)
    Button(window, text=button_text, width=30, command = click).grid(row=3, column = i)
    i+=1


window.mainloop()
```

## Other Changes you can make

You can also improve your code to be more ledgible in some other ways. Arguably the most important would be to move your code to Object Orientated Programming, I find [this guide](https://pythonprogramming.net/object-oriented-programming-crash-course-tkinter/) to be rather good!

Another change you can make is to change your `for loop`, that creates the buttons, to use Python's [enumerate](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/enumerate.html) function and [lambda](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lambda.asp):

```py
for i, button_text in enumerate(button_list):
    Button(window, text=button_text, width=30, command = lambda t=i: game(t)).grid(row=3, column = i)
```

As you can see, that one code change can improve the look of your code!

Hope this helps,

James

Comment: I just read your reply. This was my first question I uploaded on here and you are my first tutor I met. Thank you so much. You made my curiosity solved.   But I still can't understand about "you pass to the game function an integer  not a string". Why should I write 012 instead of RockPaperScissors?

Comment: @Jason that is because you send the variable `i` instead of the variable `button_text`, if you send the variable `button_text` you could use `if == 'rock' etc`